# ShareThis issue in IE7 - unable to select/click anything underneath pop up form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharethis

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'b42661f5-2dc5-4ceb-9861-3ef8a6e942be'});</script>
<div id="smTweet">
    <span st_url="" displaytext="Like" class="st_fb_like_vcount">&#160;</span>
    <span st_url="" st_title="" displaytext="Tweet" class="st_twitter_vcount">&#160;</span>
    <span st_url="" displaytext="Email" class="st_email_vcount">&#160;</span>
    <span st_url="" displaytext="Share" class="st_sharethis_vcount">&#160;</span>
</div>

<div style="width:400px;text-align:right">
    <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
</div>
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/er3Mq/

Here's the thing, when you hover over "Share" or "Email", the ShareThis form pops up.
When you close it, you can't click on "Link 1" anymore (or anything that was covered by the ShareThis form for that matter).

Any idea how to work around this issue in IE7?

Comment: So it seems! ShareThis must have updated their script between then and now. @lord_t: put something as a solution and I'll give you bounty for pointing this out.

Comment: @kei in the jsFiddle... where is the JS script? you did not choose either jQuery for your framework.... why?

Comment: @roxon: the js is external. It's from sharethis. I do not maintain their js. I chose jQuery/javascript as tags since I was hoping for jQuery/javascript solution to the problem. But since sharethis has fixed their script, it is no longer an issue.

Comment: @lord_t: Need to wait 20hrs before I can award the bounty. :/

Comment: @kei Now I got it. But, huh.... never seen: 100 bounty for a 'IT WORKS!' :)

Comment: @roxon: well I lose 100 regardless, so why not award it to someone? :D

Comment: @kei ... well may I post something too?! :D ;) good luck! make nice stuff! CIAO see ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it in ie9 with ie7 mode and there is all correct.